# Can I replace the placeholder with an editable string?

Tags: react-native

I have an input tag and instead of having a placeholder I would like to have a state variable that I can edit.

```
<Input
    placeholder={this.state.step.description}
    multiline
    inputStyle={{ maxWidth: "90%" }}
    onChangeText={step => this.setState({ step })}
    value={this.state.step}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TextInput instead of Input to replace your placeholder with editable text

```
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';
```